# Firebase realtime database sort - special characters?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a very simple Firebase query:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference nameRef = database.getReference("names");
Query query = nameRef.orderByChild("name");
```

I would like to get all names from my database in Hungarian alphabetical order. My problem is the non-english characters go to the end of the list (Hungarian names, we have some special characters comparing to english).

Example order I get from the database:

```
Aladár
Béla
Ábel
```

Expected order:

```
Aladár
Ábel
Béla
```

Because the Hungarian ABC order is this: A, Á, B, C...

Can I have this order using Firebase query? If not I have to do the sort in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Firebase does not give the option to use custom comparators when ordering. See [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order)

What you can do is you can download your strings and store them in a `ArrayList` and then use a custom `Comparator` to sort them in the Hungarian order.